# Issue on applying padding to pageview flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-animation

I have a pageview and when i added padding to the whole pageview and while scrolling when widget is about to finish the padding area the widget get removed from the screen view. This issue is not there if i remove padding. I also added clipbehaviour so that it clips to the both boundary while scrolling.

I need to have a continuous scrolling between pages.

[image]

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        padEnds: false,
        pageSnapping: false,
        clipBehavior:  Clip.none,
        children: [
          for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color:Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),

                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)
              ),
             height: 150,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Requirements :

- Need to show a page indicator.
- Height should be dynamic.

NOTE : Issue is not there if i remove padding, but i need to have a continous scroll with applying padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the clipBehaviour to `Clip.antiAlias`

I tried this and it worked well

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TempPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TempPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: PageView(
          padEnds: false,
          pageSnapping: false,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // Here is the changed made
          children: [
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color:
                        Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                            .withOpacity(1.0),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
                height: 150,
                width: double.infinity,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Other solution could be to add the padding to the page view children, like this

```dart
PageView(
  padEnds: false,
  pageSnapping: false,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  children: [
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                .withOpacity(1.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
        height: 150,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this is not the expeted outcome. On first solution if we provided antialias the padding will applied to whole pageview and what i need is that while scrolling both ends of pageview should be clipped to both screen ends.
On second solution provided, we cant provide padding to individual widgets.

Comment: Could you pleas add more info or a an example of what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're trying to achieve, then you can use `ListView` instead:

```dart
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                .withOpacity(1.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
        height: 150,
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width - 40,
      ),
  ],
)
```

[image: Demonstration]

---

If you need to have the snapping behavior as in `PageView`, you can create a custom scroll physics:

```dart
class CustomPageScrollPhysics extends PageScrollPhysics {
  final double widthReduction;

  const CustomPageScrollPhysics({super.parent, this.widthReduction = 0.0});

  @override
  CustomPageScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return CustomPageScrollPhysics(
        parent: buildParent(ancestor), widthReduction: widthReduction);
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    final actualPosition = position.copyWith(
        viewportDimension: position.viewportDimension - widthReduction);
    return super.createBallisticSimulation(actualPosition, velocity);
  }
}
```

Now use it in the `ListView` by passing the `widthReduction` amount and add `padding` with half the size to balance it's right-left padding:

```dart
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  physics: CustomPageScrollPhysics(widthReduction: 40), // (1) add this
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20), // (2) add this
  children: [
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
                .withOpacity(1.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
        height: 150,
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width - 40,
      ),
  ],
)
```

[image: Demonstration (snapping)]

Comment: i cant use listview as i need some properties of pageview like snapping, if there is anyway by which we can attain same behaviour in pageview ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by using a custom scroll physics. I've added that in my answer

Comment: That founds good, but can we do the same using pageview because we wanted have a carousel like widget. So if we are doing with listview we need to build some seperate widgets as well.

Comment: What challenge are you facing with `ListView`? Because from all the requirements you gave in the question, this solution should fit all your need. Also this is why you should have asked what you actually wanted, not how to fix the solution that you thought would solve your actual problem. See [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: ok, i have updated the question with requirements, what i need is that, i need to show a pageindicator and  as this widget comes inside an another listview, the height should be dynamic.